# Download Addgene database

Tags: database, data-download

Is anyone aware of a way to download all vector sequences from [addgene](https://www.addgene.org/) at once? As a non-profit, I'd assume they shouldn't be opposed to making this data available, but it doesn't seem to be possible. Might anyone have scraped it at some point?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: That is a very good question for Addgene. You could contact them directly.